# Argo CD and Kustomize

Tags: kustomize, argocd

all. I'm using Argo CD v1.6.1 and am trying to deploy an application using Kustomize. Argo CD doesn't seem to recognize my Kustomize manifest files. Looking at the Kustomize documentation on the Argo CD page, it looks like it only supports the following Kustomize options:

- namePrefix is a prefix appended to resources for Kustomize apps
- nameSuffix is a suffix appended to resources for Kustomize apps
- images is a list of Kustomize image overrides
- commonLabels is a string map of an additional labels

Are these the only things I'm going to be able to manipulate in my base manifest files using Kustomize? I was hoping I'd be able to use the patchesStrategicMerge option with my overlay files I've got which allow me to manipulate anything in the base.yaml files. It doesn't seem to recognize kind: Kustomization and apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

ArgoCD's main task is to deploy manifests. Kustomize is the right place for any more complex edits. It sounds like you already have an overlays structure in your kustomize application so the missing piece may be about pointing your Argo Application to the correct overlay.

Assuming you have a repo with the following structure:

```
repo
 |_ app
 |_ kustomize
   |_ base
   |  |_ resource.yml
   |  |_ kustomization.yml
   |_ overlays
      |_ prod
         |_ patch.yml
         |_ kustomization.yml
```

Then you would want your Argo Application to have:

```
source:
    repoURL: <REPO_URL>
    targetRevision: <REVISION>
    path: kustomize/overlays/prod
```

This would mean it is using your overlays kustomization file which should pull in your base kustomzition file and the patches.

The additional fields you have mentioned are like an *extra* overlay and would not be recommended to do more complex actions like a strategic merge.